# Get NGINX status with an Ansible playbook

Tags: nginx, ansible

I try to install NGINX from an Ansible playbook.

Currently I use this playbook to install it:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - apt:
        name: nginx
      when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

And it works:

```
Identity added: /runner/artifacts/46/ssh_key_data (root@debian)
SSH password: 
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.75]
TASK [apt] *********************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.75]
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.1.75               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But I would like to see the state of the NGINX service at the end of my playbook, like that:

```
Identity added: /runner/artifacts/46/ssh_key_data (root@debian)
SSH password: 
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.75]
TASK [apt] *********************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.75]
TASK [Verify nginx state] *********************************************************************
 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-14 17:59:13 CET; 20s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 1723 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1724 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1907 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 445)
     Memory: 5.6M
        CPU: 99ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─1907 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             └─1910 nginx: worker process

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.1.75               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Or something similar.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your requirement

> *I would like to see the state of the `nginx` service a the end of my playbook*

it is recommended just to use the [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) module.

```yaml
- name: Make sure 'nginx' is started
  systemd:
    name: nginx
    state: started
    enabled: yes
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result }}"
```

For later check of specific services you can use [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html).

```yaml
- name: Gathering service facts
  service_facts:

- name: Get facts
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.services['nginx'].status }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could get that detail from the sudo command here

```
  - name: check for service status
    shell: sudo service nginx status
    ignore_errors: true
    register: nginxstatus

  - name: Show service service status
    debug:
      msg: 'nginxstatus exists.' 
    when: nginxstatus.rc | int == 0
```

Comment: Squeezing commands in Ansible is not the way when there are purposed modules or facts for that, see @U880D's answer.

Comment: thats for your feedback, i need to find a 'zen of ansible' style book

Answer (score 0):

or even better

```
- name: Check status of the nginx server
  shell: 'systemctl nginx status'
  register: command_output

- debug:
         var: command_output.stdout_lines
```

Comment: If you have multiple ways to achieve the same result, post that in an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71115759/edit) of your previous answer, instead of duplicating the answers. Please note that SO is a Q&A, not a forum.

Comment: thanks, i didnt see that edit button. i will do in the future.