# Ansible service_facts filtering by partial name

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have some linux servers and want check state of services. I can easily check all processes, single process by name, but how to check for group of services with common part of name?

1. Host1 have: company1.service, company2.service, company3.service
2. Host2 have: company1.service, company3.service, company4.service
3. Host3 have: company2.service, company3.service, company4.service

I dont want hardcode this services to each host due to often changes of services sets, and thats why i need filter by partial name.

Comment: What should such a 'partial name' look like? See [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The tool should be Ansible. Describe your SW problem in detail. What is the source of the data? See [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehow vague and unspecific. However, parts of your question could be answered with the following approach.

According your description

> How to check for group of services with common part of name?

I understand that you like to check the service on a server only if a server belongs to certain group of hosts or domain in your inventory file (and if "services" are organized structured in inventory).

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Gathering Service Facts
    service_facts:
    when: "'test' in group_names and 'www.example.com' in ansible_domain"

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: services
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *************
ok: [db.example.com]
ok: [www.example.com]

TASK [Gathering Service Facts] *****
ok: [www.example.com]

TASK [Show result] *****************
ok: [db.example.com] =>
  services: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
ok: [www.example.com] =>
  services:
    ...
```

**Further Q&A**

- [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts)

According your question

> Ansible `service_facts` filtering by partial name

if you want to check for results [... from list of services using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70590709/6771046) you may have a look into the linked answered or

**Further Q&A**

- [How to check service exists ... using `service_facts` module in an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773111/6771046)
- [How to declare a variable for `service_facts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476972/6771046)
- [Get "service" status with an Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116359/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)

If all the information and links here do not answer your question you may need to provide much more information and description about your use case.