# How can I save both errors and expected output of a command into a file in Ansible-Playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am currently trying to create a playbook that runs 2 commands and saves their outputs to a file.

The problem is that I am not able to save the errors generated as the output of the 2 commands using my playbook. I can only register the expected output of commands and not the errors.

When I run my playbook for retrieving my RAM and the status of a service called ChessX, whose actual output is `Unit chessx.service could not be found.`, this line is not printed as it is being seen as an error.

My playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: chapter1
  become: yes
  ignore_errors: no
  tasks:
    - name: Q1. Find RAM
      ansible.builtin.shell: free -h | grep Mem | awk {'print $2'}
      register: ram
    - debug: var=ram.stdout_lines

    - name: Q2. Find status
      ansible.builtin.shell: systemctl status chessx | grep Active | awk '{print $2$3}'
      register: chessStatus
    - debug: var=chessStatus.stdout_lines

    - name: Q3. Save content to file in /home/gwen/Desktop/out.txt
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
          RAM={{ ram.stdout }}
          SERVICE={{ chessStatus.stdout }}
        dest: /home/gwen/Desktop/out.txt
```

The content of the `out.txt` file is as follows:

```ini
RAM=2.9Gi
SERVICE=
```

How can I modify my script so that the `SERVICE` variable will also include the `Unit chessx.service could not be found.` error?

Comment: Check `chessStatus.stderr`. Besides that, you should really consider obeying ansible top good practice: "If there is a module or a variable to do what I need, don't use shell". You can get memory information from `ansible_mem*` facts on the hosts (check `ansible -i your_inventory your_host -m setup` for a quick view) and you can check availability/status of a systemd service using the [`ansible.builtin.systemd_service` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_service_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-systemd-service-module)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this solves my issue! Also how can I learn about which modules will be containing which information I need?

Comment: By spending a lot of time in the documentation and experimenting. For modules a good place to start: `https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your Use Case, all could be achieved already just with out-of-box functionality, specifically [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts).

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - 'hardware'
    - '!min'
    - '!all'

  tasks:

  - service_facts:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.memfree_mb }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.services['chessx'].status }}"
```

will collect the information. If [Caching facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) is enabled it is already written into files on the Control Node.

**Further Reading**

- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576)
- [An introduction to Ansible facts](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/playing-ansible-facts)
- [How to cache Ansible facts](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-fact-cache-redis)

and

- [Is it possible to gather only specific facts in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692925/6771046)
- [How to gather `ansible_facts` inside of a role only when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470572/6771046)
- [How to pass variable from Ansible `service_facts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76911066/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to start stopped services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71953222/6771046)
- [Start only specific `systemd` service from list of services using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70590709/6771046)
- [Get NGINX status with an Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116359/6771046)
- [Ansible `service_facts` filtering by partial name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71420765/6771046)